# Node.js/Express - Routing More Than One Form Post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm working on webpage that has two separate forms on it, with two separate form actions. I can get one form to work, but I can't get both to work. I've got post route *router.post('/direct-user',...)* and post route *router.post('/other-user', ...)*, if I change one of those to just router.post('/',...) then it works just fine.

I suspect there's something wrong in my **app.js** route declarations, but I can't figure it out.

Any guidance would be super awesome.

My app structure looks like this:

```
/project
    /routes
        index.js
        requser.js
    /views
        error.hbs
        index.hbs
        layout.hbs
        requser.hbs
    app.js
    package.json
```

And here's my main app file which has my module imports, route locations, and error handling.
**app.js**

```
// Module imports //
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(validator());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// Routes and views //
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/user/:id', require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/user-update', require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/requser', require('./routes/requser'));
app.use('/direct-user', require('./routes/requser'));
app.use('/other-user', require('./routes/requser'));


// Catch 404 and forward to error handler //
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        var err = new Error('Not Found');
        err.status = 404;
        next(err);
});

// Development error handler; will print stacktrace //
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
        app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
                res.status(err.status || 500);
                res.render('error', {
                        message: err.message,
                        error: err
                });
        });
}

// Production error handler; no stacktraces leaked to user //
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
                message: err.message,
                error: {}
        });
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here's my requser file which includes one get route to load the empty form, and two post routes to handle the input from one of the two forms.
**requser.js**

```
// Module imports //
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


// GET request user form //
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('requser', {
        title: 'User Request'
    });
});


// POST /direct-user //
router.post('/direct-user', function(req, res) {
    // Validate form contents
    // ...

    // Assuming all is well
    console.log('Direct user requested');
    res.send('cool');
});

// POST other-user //
router.post('/other-user', function(req, res) {
    // Validate form contents
    // ...

    // Assuming all is well
    console.log('Other user requested');
    res.send('cool');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And lastly, my form view/template.
**requser.hbs**

```
<div class="container">
<h1>User Request</h1>

<!-- Start of direct user creation form //////////////////////////////// -->
<form method="post" action="/direct-user">
    <!-- First name, last name -->
    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- Submit button -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End row -->
</form> <!-- End form -->


<!-- Start of other user creation form //////////////////////////////// -->
<form method="post" action="/other-user">
    <!-- First name, last name -->
    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- Submit button -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the routing middleware in an incorrect way.

```
app.use('/user/:id', require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/user-update', require('./routes/user'));
app.use('/requser', require('./routes/requser'));
app.use('/direct-user', require('./routes/requser'));
app.use('/other-user', require('./routes/requser'));
```

These lines are the problematic ones.

Let's take one of these as an example, the third one, as that one by itself is enough to take care of the `/direct-user` and `/other-user` endpoints.

What that line tells express to do is:

> When a request hits the server whose path starts with /requser, pass that request to the requser router middleware and it will handle the rest.

Let's say that your request is to the path `/requser/direct-user`. That request will be passed to the `requser` middleware and that middleware will than match the remaining part (`/direct-user`) and correctly invoke the relevant callback.

Without knowing where your form posts the data, I can't help you further. But you should check that both forms post their data to `/requser/direct-user` and `/requser/other-user`, respectively and it should work.

Comment: That works! I was just missing the /requser/ part of the action in my forms. Thanks Can!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use('/user/:id', require('./routes/user'));
```

All those line of codes are telling your app to use the routes exported from that file using '/user/:id' as prefix. So, if you want to use all routes in that file, all routes now start with '/users/:id' + the route you created in the file.

Let's say you have the following route

```
router.post('/direct-user', function(req, res) {
    // Validate form contents
    // ...

    // Assuming all is well
    console.log('Direct user requested');
    res.send('cool');
});
```

Then your real route will be '/users/:id/direct-user'